# How to read uses input and check if the inputed url is from youtube.com

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a prompt that accepts user input, what I'm trying to do is read the users input and determine if what they inputted is a youtube iframe URL but my code is not working I think my checkUrl() function is not receiving the urlInput correctly and that's why it's not checking if the inputted url contains youtube.com but I'm not a 100% sure. My current code is attached below.

```js
      
       function inputPrompt() {
         globalThis.urlInput = prompt("Enter URL:");
        if (urlInput == null || urlInput == "") {
            alert("Null");
        } else {
           checkUrl();
        }
    }
      
    function checkUrl(){    
      var iframes = urlInput;
        var key = /https:\/\/www.youtube.com/;

        for (var i = 0; i != iframes.length; ++i) {
            var match = iframes[i].src.search(key);
            if (match != -1) {
                alert('is youTube url');
            } else{
               alert('not youtube url');
            }
        }
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="inputPrompt()">check Url</button>
```

Comment: You need to be specific as to what exactly is not working.

Comment: I just edit my question and added where the error might be arising from. The code should alert "is youtube URL" if the inputted URL contains youtube.com.@Talha awan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a for loop nor do you need to try and retrieve a non-existent 'src' property if all you want is to check if user input starts with `https://www.youtube.com` or not.

```js
function inputPrompt() {
  globalThis.urlInput = prompt("Enter URL:");
  if (urlInput == null || urlInput == "") {
    alert("Null");
  } else {
    checkUrl();
  }
}

function checkUrl(){    
  var iframes = urlInput;
  var key = /https:\/\/www.youtube.com/;

  if (iframes.search(key) != -1) {
    alert('is youTube url');
  } else{
    alert('not youtube url');
  }
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', inputPrompt);
```

```html
<button>check Url</button>
```